# Does there exist such set $A \subset R$, satisfying the following two conditions?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, real-numbers

Does there exist such set $A \subset R$, satisfying the following conditions:

1)$x - \lfloor x \rfloor$ is injective on $A$

2)$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ $A^{3n} \cup A = A^{-3n} \cup A = \mathbb{R}$

Here $A^m$ is defined as $\{x^m |x \in A\}$.

If such $A$ exists, then $-A$ satisfies those conditions as well. However nothing else is currently known to me about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such set.

As $x^3=1$ only has the root $x=1$ in $\mathbb R$, condition 2) for $n=1$ requires $1\in A$. Similarly $-1\in A$. Yet $1-\lfloor1\rfloor=0=(-1)-\lfloor-1\rfloor$.